# Raspberry Pi RFID interfacing

Tags: python, uart, rfid

I am trying to interface my raspberry pi to a RFID reader, to make an library management system. I have brought a RFID reader whose data sheet can be found [here](http://robokitsworld.com/downloads/Robokits_RFID_UART.pdf). I have found a [python program](https://gist.github.com/mattgorecki/6085344) which can get data from RFID reader.

I am pretty new to raspbeery pi and not quite sure about how to connect this reader to my pie . As far as I understand, I will have to connect TX , SEL pin to a GP/IO pin as well as Vcc and GND . Do I need to use a voltage shifter to make sure that input voltage level in TX is below 5v. Can anyone guide me on connecting the reader to pi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the serial link rather than Wiegand you can just connect SEL to 5V.

So one way of wiring is

```
RFID        Pi
pin         pin
1 VCC       2 (5V)
2 GND       6 (Ground)
3 BEEP      ---
4 NC        ---
5 NC        ---
6 SEL       2 (5V)
7 TX        10 (RXD) Using a voltage divider
8 D1        ---
9 D0        ---
```

It is important that you use a voltage divider (pair of resistors, google) to cut 5V to a Pi safe 3V3 on the TX/RXD link.

The code you reference seems to have little relevance to your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. Correct me if I am wrong. With the python code in link, I should be able to read serial data from my RFID reader. right?

Comment: @AmeliePeter I don't think so, the data read by the Python seems to be formatted differently with line feeds terminating the readings.  I wouldn't be overly concerned at this stage, the needed code is fairly trivial.

Comment: Can you please suggest me the correct code to read serial data from my rfid reader?